# How can I start chrome custom tabs in incognito mode?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using custom tabs for OAuth and don't want chrome to keep cookies when the login session is over. Google's app-auth library doesn't give any support for that. I thought, maybe opening up the custom tab in `incognito mode` would help me to solve this problem. Has anyone before run into the same problem. In custom tabs documentation I couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: There is no support for creating an Incognito Custom Chrome Tab on Android. There is no way to clear the cache programmatically as well.

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-chrome-incognito-custom-tabs/) and introduced [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-reviews/c/d1901HSe8nc), it's now possible to use custom tabs with incognito mode.

Do so by adding the `"com.google.android.apps.chrome.EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB"` extra to the `Intent` like so:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build()
        .apply {
            if (openNewIncognitoTab) {
                intent.putExtra("com.google.android.apps.chrome.EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB", true)
            }
        }
```

Depending on the Chrome version, users will likely have to manually enable two Chrome flags for this to work:

```
chrome://flags/#cct-incognito
chrome://flags/#cct-incognito-available-to-third-party
```

Comment: Note that this intent flag is ignored when set by 3rd party apps. So it's not possible to do this in general. It only works for 1st party apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to start a Custom Tab in incognito mode.