# Can we restrict screen capture using secure flag for chrome custom tab in android?

Tags: android, screen-capture, chrome-custom-tabs, flag-secure

I am using chrome custom tab to display data in one screen. But data is sensitive and need to protect it by disabling screen capture functionality of devices.
It would be great help if any one could explain me how can I achieve this requirement for custom chrome tabs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not have much control over CCT as it is a part of Chrome, a third-party app.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible. The reason is that the Custom Tab runs in the browser process, not the host app process.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots are disabled by default, but only when launching the tab in [incognito mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443545/how-can-i-start-chrome-custom-tabs-in-incognito-mode).
Chrome must have been built with `allow_incognito_custom_tabs_from_third_party`.