# How can a native Android App support multiple SSO providers and allow users to login with different accounts without requiring manual logout in Chrome

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, chrome-custom-tabs, android-deep-link

I am trying to implement an SSO login in a native Android app and want to follow the best practices outlined in [RFC 8252 (OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252). This requires using [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) rather than  `WebViews`:

> B.2.  Android Implementation Details
>
> Apps can initiate an authorization request in the browser, without the user leaving the app, through the Android Custom Tab feature, which implements the in-app browser tab pattern.  The user's default browser can be used to handle requests when no browser supports Custom Tabs.

The login process is working correctly, but once a user logs in with a specific account in a Chrome Custom Tab, it is not possible to log in with a different account without manually logging out in Chrome.

On iOS, this issue can be addressed using an [`ASWebAuthenticationSession` with the `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession/3237231-prefersephemeralwebbrowsersessio) parameter set to `true`, but this solution is not available on Android.

Chrome does offer [experimental support for Incognito Custom Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540492/293878), but this requires user opt-in and displays a privacy warning when the deep link to the app is fired.

I am looking for a solution that allows a native Android app to support multiple SSO providers and allows users to log in with different accounts without requiring manual logout in Chrome.